# random password does not choose every condition that user choose

Tags: python, algorithm, password-generator

I want to make a password generator I let user to choose upper, digits and, symbols but I have problem with Random part when my code choose a random password from phrase According to the conditions selected by the user, one of the conditions may not be fulfilled.
For example, all the selected phrase may be lowercase, but the user has activated the uppercase condition

```
import  string
import secrets


def random_password_generator(upper=True, digits=True, symbols=False, length=12):
    a_l = string.ascii_lowercase
    a_u = string.ascii_uppercase
    phrase = a_l
    if upper:
        phrase += a_u

    if digits:
        phrase += string.digits

    if symbols:
        phrase += string.punctuation

    password = ''.join(secrets.choice(phrase) for i in range(length))

    return password

a = random_password_generator()
print(a)
```

Comment: Can you show a test-case that fails?

Comment: Debug a failing example.

Answer (score 0):

secrets.choice(phrase) chooses a random character out of the phrase you give it. You perform that operation 10 times. There is no guarantee that during those 10 times, the random choice will fall in any of the categories you have added to your phrase.

Comment: about  length that was a mistake but the real problem is there's no guarantee  that when user set digits true or symbols true secrets.choice() chose a phrase that include symbols and  digits

Answer (score 0):

```
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(phrase) for i in range(10))
```

You're choosing ten random letters from `phrase`.

Even if `phrase` includes uppercase letters as possible choices, there's no guarantee that the random selections will actually include any uppercase letters.  It might just happen to randomly choose all lowercase letters.

Same thing with digits and symbols.

Also, why are you choosing ten letters?  You're ignoring the `length` parameter.

Comment: about  length that was a mistake but the real problem is there's no guarantee  that when user set digits true or symbols true secrets.choice() chose a phrase that include symbols and  digits

Answer (score 0):

Take the input length and divide it into symbol categories. Randomly select characters from that category and append them to the password. Finally, randomly shuffle all characters of the password.

Dividing the input length into categories could be done according to some weights that you choose and hard-code.

For example, if you were to assign the following weights,

| Category | weight |
| --- | --- |
| Upper | 5 |
| Lower | 5 |
| Digits | 3 |
| Symbols | 2 |

Then, you can decide how many characters to use for each category. For example, if they ask for a length of 12, with upper, lower, and digits. The total weight for upper, lower, and digits is 5 + 5 + 3 = 13, therefore max(( 5 / 13 ) * 12, 1) = 4 characters should be upper case, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Your function argument to decide wether symbols should be included is called `symbols`. However, you then assign `string.punctuation` to a variable with the same name.

This means, the following if statement `if symbol:` is actually the same as `if string.punctuation`, which always resolves to `True`, no matter what boolean value your symbol parameter carried before string.punctuation was assigned to it.

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```py
import  string
import secrets


def random_password_generator(upper=True, digits=True, include_symbols=False, length=12):
    a_l = string.ascii_lowercase
    a_u = string.ascii_uppercase
    all_symbols = string.punctuation # make sure this is a different variable
    phrase = a_l
    if upper:
        phrase += a_u

    if digits:
        phrase += string.digits

    if include_symbols:
        phrase += all_symbols

    password = ''.join(secrets.choice(phrase) for i in range(10))

    return password

a = random_password_generator()
print(a)
```

I hope this was understandable.

Comment: Valid point, although does not entirely answer his question

Comment: I think his problem was that even if setting symbols to False, he got a password with symbols (for the explained reason). Using proper variable names, he gets the password "According to the conditions selected by the user".

Comment: that is not the problem However I edited  that